# Count acitivites in Leads

Tags: community

Is there a way to count activities on leads ?. Is it by using a custom report through the report type or Can we so it using apex triggers and how?\

I would like to know how to track the activities when the lead is converted to an opportunity ?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with reporting.  You could create a new report type with Lead as the primary object and add activities as the child object.  Then you could run a report and group the report by leads.  This would show you all activities for each lead.

You could simulate a rollup summary field to count the child objects with Triggers or Batch Apex.  I would recomend not doing that as there are already some solid apps out there that can do this for you

[Rollup Helper](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009i3UpEAI) on the App Exchange

[Declarative Rollup Summary Tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Declarative_Rollup_Summary_Tool_for_Force.com_Lookup_Relationships), a great open sounce project by Andy Fawcett